Parse dashboard: unable to connect to the server
I am using parse server by bitnami on aws and i am completely new here dont know whats going on but my parse dashboard is showing unable to connect to the server
(I am using windows pc)
Screenshot while accessing parse dashboard
Even if i try to connect it from EC2 instance connect it always show me this error
Screenshot while using EC2 instance connect
i have read many solutions like editing inbounds and adding ssh accessing method and it is already addedd in my case i even tried deleting and adding all inbounds again
Other is replaceing serverURL:- localhost with actual ip address
but i dont know where to find the exact file where i have to make changes, so i have edited all the config.json that i could find but still the problems remains same
please help me i dont know what to do ???
i am trying to the connect to the parse server from my android application but the course i purchased is 4 year old and now everything is changed

I can't offer a complete solution, but I experimented with a Bitnami AMI today, and found it does not support EC2 Instance Connect. Try SSHing from your local system instead (I've heard PuTTY is a popular Windows SSH client).
